# Is it possible to get ARSCNFaceGeometry from an Image using ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Does anyone know a way to generate an ARSCNFaceGeometry from an image using ARKit?  By default, the ARSCNFaceGeometry is created in Swift from the device's camera feed.

It looks like with ARKit3 there are only currently 3 possible ways to initialize an ARSCNFaceGeometry, using a NSCoder, MTLDevice, or SCNGeometrySource.  Based on this, it seems that it is not possible to auto-generate an ASCNFaceGeometry from an image, but I wanted to see if anyone may have found a way?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referencing a still image?  Such as a UIImage?  I believe that you must take  at least the pixel buffers from an ARSession's camera feed to integrate the ARSCNFaceGeometry (obviously on a device that has a supported TrueDepth camera).  That said, would using the Vision framework, and its facial tracking technology, achieve your desired result?

Comment: Yes, still image.  Thanks for the response.  That's pretty much what I figured.  Basically I created an app that uses ARSCNFaceGeometry to distort users faces and I wanted to use some still images for promotional materials.  Vision framework could work but would require me to rebuild everything.

Comment: That seems correct.  It would likely be an extensive amount of effort to rebuild everything, and have to handle all of the work ARKit is doing for you.  As far as I understand, the TrueDepth camera uses its mix of dot-projection and depth masks to track faces, hence its inability to do so on a 2D image.